# open second Accordion Menu tab using Jquery

Tags: jquery

Iam new to jQuery.I want to open the second tab(operations) as deafult in page load.

```
<HTML>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<br></br>
<H2> Automation </H2>
<br></br>
<ul id="accordion">
    <li>Operations</li>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Add</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>

    </ul>
    <li>Deatils</li>
    <ul>
    <br></br>
<table border="" bordercolor="#FFCC00" style="background-color:#FFFFFF" width="400" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="1">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="Radio" name="radio_name" value="radio_val">1</td>
        <td>.</td>
        <td>.</td>
        <td>.......</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="Radio" name="radio_name" value="radio_val">2</td>
        <td>.</td>
        <td>.</td>
        <td>.......</td>
    </tr>

</table>

    </ul>
        </ul>  

</BODY>

</HTML>
```

I used following code.but it is not working

```
     <SCRIPT>   

 $("#accordion > li").click(function(){

    $('#accordion li:eq(1)').show();

        if(false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
            $('#accordion > ul').slideUp(300);
    }
    $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
});

$('#accordion > ul:eq(0)').show();

</SCRIPT>
```

while page loading how can i set second tab as open default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are not using JQuery accordion completely.

Here is a [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9YNTt/) for JQuery accordion and open second tab by default.

**HTML**

```
<br></br>
<H2> Automation </H2>
<br></br>
<ul id="accordion">
   <h3>Operations</h3>
    <div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Add</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>

    </ul>
    </div>
    <h3>Deatils</h3>
    <ul>
    <br></br>
<table border="" bordercolor="#FFCC00" style="background-color:#FFFFFF" width="400" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="1">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="Radio" name="radio_name" value="radio_val">1</td>
        <td>.</td>
        <td>.</td>
        <td>.......</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="Radio" name="radio_name" value="radio_val">2</td>
        <td>.</td>
        <td>.</td>
        <td>.......</td>
    </tr>

</table>

    </ul>
        </ul>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion("activate",1);
  });
```

Check the HTML changes I have made.

[Check how to perform JQuery accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)

Answer (score 1):

```
    <script>   
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#accordion li:eq(1)').show(); // second tab show
 $('#accordion li:eq(1) ul').show(); // second tab show

        $("#accordion > li").click(function(){

            if($(this).next().is(':visible')) {
                $('#accordion > ul').slideUp(300);
            }
           $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
        });

    });
    </script>
```